# Apex delete stale jobs

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a few apex jobs which become stale (i.e. they just lie around in scheduled jobs queue with no nextfiretime) if an exception is hit while running the schedulable class. I cannot abort these jobs using the System.abort(jobId) since the job is not running. What is the best way to delete such stuck/erroneous apex jobs with no next fire time? Should I just query the cronTrigger objects and delete them?

```
List<CronTrigger> ctriggers = [SELECT Id, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger
                      WHERE CronJobDetail.Name like 'JobName%'
                      And NextFireTime = NULL];

delete ctriggers;
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried deleting the cronTrigger objects but hit the following DML exception -> DML operation DELETE not allowed on CronTrigger

Comment: And what happened when you called `abortJob`? This is information you can [edit] into your post to make it easier to answer.

Comment: N.B. Per [SFDC Object ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm?search_text=crontrigger), `CronTrigger` or `AsyncApexJob` doesn't support delete call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to think I've had this issue before and solved it using, e.g.:

```
System.purgeOldAsyncJobs(Date.today().addMonths(-12));
```

You might want to test it on a smaller date range though.

See [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) for details.